# Why does this code show the value of a global variable instead of a class variable when using a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, scope, list-comprehension

So I've seen a code that goes like

```
name = "Python"

class Language:
    name = "Java"
    list1 = [name] * 3  
    list2 = [name for i in range(3)]

print(Language.list1)
print(Language.list2)
```

And the output is

```
['Java', 'Java', 'Java']
['Python', 'Python', 'Python']
```

Why is the output not "Java" both times?

Comment: Hah, that's a fun edge case you've got there. I'm sure there's a rational explanation, but wheeew!

Comment: i guess you wouldn't be able to explain it ryt

Comment: The duplicate question linked has a decent explanation. I learned something!

Comment: am kinda new to python... i kinda need explanation in my own question please. if its possible

Comment: Basically, the scope of a class definition does not behave like other scopes, and is skipped when a list comprehension or function needs to access a nonlocal variables.

Comment: If the class namespace wasn't skipped, you'd be able to access class variables in your methods, too, even though that scope didn't exist anymore.